# Django: Initial value for a ModelSerializer field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm writing a Django app using `django==1.10` and `djangorestframework==3.4.6`

Please consider the following code:

I have two models:

```
class BaselineModel(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey('custom_auth.User', blank=True)
    weight = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class DosageModel(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey('custom_auth.User', blank=True)
    udca = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And a Serializer:

```
class DosageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ("subject",)
        model = DosageModel
```

**Question:** How can I set the initial value for `DosageModel.weight` to `BaselineModel.weight`?

**Use Case:**
Weights initial value will be the weight registered at Baseline. The user has the option to overwrite the initial value.

[image]

**Edit:** The initial value should be "initial", meaning it should be displayed i the HTML input field before the data object is created.

Comment: did you already try to use the http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#default option?

Comment: Im not using SerializerFields, Im using ModelSerializer. If a solution is possible using SerializerFields, please provide a code example :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could not use `default` method on `weight` serializer since `subject` isn't cleaned at that time. I used a model level validation to achieve the result.

Try this:

```
class DosageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    weight = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = DosageModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        if 'weight' not in data:
            data['weight'] = BaselineModel.objects.get(subject=data['subject']).weight
    return data
```

I assumed that user provides `subject` when creating the `DosageModel` object. If it's not the case please provide more details.

Comment: The validate is called at validation (when client POST a result), right? 
I need to pre-populate the field with an initial value before a POST request is send til the server.

Comment: Validation will be called when creating or updating an instance.Or do you mean that weight field should be filled with that value when getting a `Dosage` with `weight == None`?

Comment: Yes, Im looking for a way to fill the weight field with an initial value before create or update. I'll update the question to be more precise, my apologies!

Answer (score 2):

You can define an extra field (such as my_weight) for using `initial` argument in  your serializer field.
Here is example code:

```
class DosageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_weight = serializers.SmallIntegerField(source="weight", initial=BaselineModel.objects.first().weight)

   class Meta:
        exclude = ("subject",)
        model = DosageModel
```

May be your initial value dependents to user, in which case the `BaselineModel` will be filtered based on your desired `subject`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
class DosageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    weight = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=BaselineModel.objects.get(pk=<your pk>)    

    class Meta:
        exclude = ("subject",)
        model = DosageModel
```

But you will run into a problem: The Default value will be fetched once at the start of the server.

```
class DosageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DosageSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.BaselineDefault = BaselineModel.objects.get(pk=<your pk>)

    weight = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=BaselineDefault    

    class Meta:
        exclude = ("subject",)
        model = DosageModel
```

This will fetch the value every time the Model is initialized. This works with ModelForms and I am not sure if the RestSerializers behave the same way.